# Spring security using jpa and hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

i am new to spring, hibernate and jpa. here i am trying to implement spring security using hibernate .for some reason i got this error message .

```
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: punit
    ...]
Jul 07, 2014 4:16:56 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator instantiateExplicitConnectionProvider
INFO: HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider
Jul 07, 2014 4:16:56 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
Jul 07, 2014 4:16:56 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFactory
Jul 07, 2014 4:16:56 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Jul 07, 2014 4:16:57 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
Hibernate: 
    alter table user_roles 
        drop 
        foreign key FK734299499D6ADC74
Hibernate: 
    alter table user_roles 
        drop 
        foreign key FK734299494295A054
Hibernate: 
    drop table if exists Goal
Hibernate: 
    drop table if exists RegForm
Hibernate: 
    drop table if exists Usersfirst
Hibernate: 
    drop table if exists roles
Hibernate: 
    drop table if exists user_roles
Hibernate: 
    drop table if exists users
Hibernate: 
    create table Goal (
        id bigint not null auto_increment,
        minutes integer not null,
        primary key (id)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB
Hibernate: 
    create table RegForm (
        id bigint not null auto_increment,
        address varchar(255),
        description TEXT,
        name varchar(255),
        phonenumber integer not null,
        pic varchar(255),
        place varchar(255),
        type varchar(255),
        url varchar(255),
        primary key (id)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB
Hibernate: 
    create table Usersfirst (
        id bigint not null auto_increment,
        password varchar(255),
        role varchar(255),
        uname varchar(255),
        primary key (id)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB
Hibernate: 
    create table roles (
        id integer not null auto_increment,
        role varchar(255),
        primary key (id)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB
Hibernate: 
    create table user_roles (
        role_id integer,
        user_id integer not null,
        primary key (role_id, user_id),
        unique (user_id)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB
Hibernate: 
    create table users (
        id integer not null auto_increment,
        login varchar(255),
        password varchar(255),
        primary key (id)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB
Hibernate: 
    alter table user_roles 
        add index FK734299499D6ADC74 (role_id), 
        add constraint FK734299499D6ADC74 
        foreign key (role_id) 
        references roles (id)
Hibernate: 
    alter table user_roles 
        add index FK734299494295A054 (user_id), 
        add constraint FK734299494295A054 
        foreign key (user_id) 
        references users (id)
Jul 07, 2014 4:17:02 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000230: Schema export complete
Jul 07, 2014 4:17:02 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@56b8abe3: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,userDAOImpl,goalRepository,usersRepository,roleDAOImpl,regformRepository,helloController,goalController,minutesController,regFormService,roleServiceImpl,userServiceImpl,customUserDetailsService,goalService,usersService,org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor#0,entityManagerFactory,transactionManager,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,dataSource,org.springframework.security.filterChains,org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy,org.springframework.security.web.PortMapperImpl#0,org.springframework.security.web.PortResolverImpl#0,org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0,org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy#0,org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler#0,org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0,org.springframework.security.userDetailsServiceFactory,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher#0,org.springframework.security.authenticationManager,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
Jul 07, 2014 4:17:02 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry destroySingletons
INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@56b8abe3: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,userDAOImpl,goalRepository,usersRepository,roleDAOImpl,regformRepository,helloController,goalController,minutesController,regFormService,roleServiceImpl,userServiceImpl,customUserDetailsService,goalService,usersService,org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor#0,entityManagerFactory,transactionManager,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,dataSource,org.springframework.security.filterChains,org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy,org.springframework.security.web.PortMapperImpl#0,org.springframework.security.web.PortResolverImpl#0,org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0,org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy#0,org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler#0,org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0,org.springframework.security.userDetailsServiceFactory,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher#0,org.springframework.security.authenticationManager,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
Jul 07, 2014 4:17:02 PM org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean destroy
INFO: Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'punit'
Jul 07, 2014 4:17:02 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDAOImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.basicsinjava.repository.UserDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.basicsinjava.repository.UserDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:988)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
    ... 24 more

Jul 07, 2014 4:17:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDAOImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.basicsinjava.repository.UserDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.basicsinjava.repository.UserDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:988)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
    ... 24 more

Jul 07, 2014 4:17:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Jul 07, 2014 4:17:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/firstSpring] startup failed due to previous errors
Jul 07, 2014 4:17:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jul 07, 2014 4:17:03 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/firstSpring] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Jul 07, 2014 4:17:03 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/firstSpring] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jul 07, 2014 4:17:03 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jul 07, 2014 4:17:03 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jul 07, 2014 4:17:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 16310 ms
```

here is my userdaoimpl class:

```
package com.basicsinjava.repository;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.basicsinjava.model.User;



@Repository
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private Session openSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    public User getUser(String login) {
        List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
        Query query = openSession().createQuery("from User u where u.login = :login");
        query.setParameter("login", login);
        userList = query.list();
        if (userList.size() > 0)
            return userList.get(0);
        else
            return null;    
    }

}
```

my jpa configuration :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.basicsinjava"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="punit"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            </bean>
        </property>

        <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
                <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
                <entry key="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            </map>
        </property>

    </bean>

        <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

        <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/firstSpring?autoReconnect=true" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>




</beans>
```

i am following this tutorial http://fruzenshtein.com/spring-mvc-security-mysql-hibernate/

for some reason i can't tackle this situation .
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Please format your question well. I m not getting why you posted two stack trace? are they same?

Comment: How you are init. bean `SessionFactory`? Any xml code for that? looks like hibernate properties file path is not correctly provided.

Comment: @sudeepcv , You are using bean `sessionFactory` but in provided config I can't see any bean definition as `sessionFactory`.

Comment: then i would like to use @PersistenceContext
 private EntityManager em;   insted of sessionFacory then what would be the code? Thanks

Comment: i am new to all these technologies. i am using spring jap with hibernate but i am not sure about the spring security tutorial which i mentioned in the question . a brief explanation would be very helpful; thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can understand your config, you have a `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` bean that will expose an `EntityManagerFactory`. So you can autowire an `EntityManagerFactory` in any of your beans.

But you try to autowire a `SessionFactory` that does not seem to be defined anywhere in you configuration.

So you have few solutions :

- either stick to JPA, inject a `EntityManagerFactory` in your DAO and use it directly (following extracted from Spring Reference Manual)

  ```
  private EntityManagerFactory emf;

  @PersistenceUnit
  public void setEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
      this.emf = emf;
  }
  // ... later in code
      EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
  ```
- once you have an `EntityManager`, you can also unwrap a `Session` from it :

  ```
      Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
  ```
- you can instead declare a `FactoryBean<SessionFactory>` with an injected `EntityManagerFactory` (in fact, it will be a `HibernateEntityManagerFactory`)

  ```
  @Bean 
  class SessionFactoryBean implements FactoryBean<SessionFactory> {
      private EntityManagerFactory emf;
      private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

      @PersistenceUnit
      public void setEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
          this.emf = emf;
          sessionFactory = ((HibernateEntityManagerFactory) emf).getSessionFactory();
      }
      public SessionFactory getObject() {
          return sessionFactory;
      }
  }
  ```

  and then you can safely use an autowired `SessionFactory`.

Comment: I have one question, how the line `private EntityManagerFactory emf;` will be get init.? we not added `@Autowired` to it to refer bean from config file.Do we need to.

Comment: @Amogh : according to Spring Reference Manual the `@PersistenceUnit` annotation is enough to get the `EntityManagerFactory` injected.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your xml file

```
<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

Spring security using aop, default aop in spring create proxy objects using interface, not specific class. This code tell to spring to use CGLIB aop.

You can read more here [spring proxying](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch08s06.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But its not helping